# run a function using multiple input row data in seqRFLP

Tags: dataframe, pipe, sequence, enzyme, restriction

I am interested on the frag.dat function on seqRFLP, but this function only work for single enzyme per run (enzymes = X).

```
frag.dat(fil = fas, enznames = X, enzdata = enzdata)
```

Here is the simple example

```
directory <- system.file("extdata", package = "seqRFLP")
path <- file.path(directory, "try.fasta")
fas <- read.fasta(path)
frag.dat(fil = fas, enznames = "AluI", enzdata = enzdata)
```

and the result

```
enznames recogSite          cutting_Site
>try     AluI     AG'CT 55,94,244,256,343,553
```

But if i want multiple enzyme at one run, then

```
frag.dat(fil = fas, enznames = "AluI", "TaqI", enzdata = enzdata)
Error in frag.dat(fil = fas, enznames = "AluI", "TaqI", enzdata = enzdata) : 
  unused argument ("TaqI")
```

Any sugestion to run multiple enzyme at once? Thanks in advance.